# Using meteor's simple:rest package in publications with arguments

Tags: javascript, rest, meteor

I a meteor app, using the simple:rest package to access publications works very nicely!

However, I didn't manage yet to GET a publication that requires an argument.

The [docs](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-rest/blob/master/packages/rest/README.md#publications) say nothing about publications with arguments.

- When I call the GET URL without argument http://localhost:3000/publications/export/, I get an error message (as I check for the argument in my publication)
- When I call get URL with attached argument: http://localhost:3000/publications/export/12345/ the main app gets loaded instead (well, with some broken links to images)
- When I add an url option to the publication

```
  Meteor.publish("export", function exportPublication(id) {...}, {
    url: "export/:0",
  })
```

it doesn't help, I still get the main app.
The example at https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-rest/blob/master/packages/rest/rest-tests.js suggests that using the URL option seems to be the correct way to define a route for a publication with arguments.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this package myself, but I think you need to add the parameter to the publish function, like this:

```
  Meteor.publish("export", function exportPublication(id) {...}, {
    url: "export/:0",
  })
```

and you can access `id` in the code that retrieves the data. If you are treating it as a number, you may need to parse it: `parseInt(id, 10)`

Also I would use postman or curl to access the URL (it sounds like you are using the browser)

Comment: Right, I was missing the `id` argument in the example above - but not in my code, I corrected this above. I tried curl, but same result. When I access `http://localhost:3000/publications/api-routes`, I get the JSON returned. But with `curl http://localhost:3000/publications/export/123` I get an html page that looks pretty much like the main app page.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, when I publish the url as `export/:0`, then it is mapped to `http://localhost:3000/export/123` - but not to `http://localhost:3000/publications/export/123`. I thought the "publications" would be added automatically.